# UWP database with SQLite and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to create and use database in UWP with SQLite and Entity Framework.

I am following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started) step by step.

The problem is, when I run

```
Add-Migration MyFirstMigration
```

in console, this error shows up:

> Add-Migration : Cannot add the link because the source file C:\Users\Tomi\Desktop\sqewl\3letnik\Razvoj mobilnih reçitev\App1\App1\Migrations\2017011511
>   1417_MyFirstMigration.cs cannot be found.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-Migration MyFirstMigration
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Add-Migration], COMException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Add-Migration

What am I doing wrong here?

**Solution:**

I had 'š' in folder name and changed it to 's'.

Comment: Is your UWP app the startup project? Is it set to x86?

Comment: File cannot be found, Maybe EF has problem with path "Razvoj mobilnih reçitev"

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem! I had 'š' in folder name and changed it to 's'.

Comment: According to your comment, it seems you've solved this problem. If so, I'd suggest your write an answer by yourself. This will help others who encounter the same problem later. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In the console try this.

```
Add-Migration -Name YourMigrationName -Project ProjectName -StartupProject ProjectName
```

I have been hitting the same error. And there are no clear documentations about it. Hope it helps for someone

Answer (score -2):

entityframework does not support sqlite migration.

Comment: that's not true... see the OP's linked tutorial

Comment: Dear James, this tutorial is written for other DBs, but for SQlite is not working correctly, you can refer to sqlite website they have acknowledged that they have problem with migration, you have to do it manually using SQL statements but not through EF. myinformation is few months old, if you have any example of working sqlite migration through EF core please let me know. I will be grateful

Comment: If you read the tutorial, it clearly states that you must do a migration.  If it does not support a migration, then why would they say to do one?